# Dynamic Components: React vs Vue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In React we can add dynamic component this way (I grabbed it from the react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

```
import React from 'react';
import { PhotoStory, VideoStory } from './stories';

const components = {
  photo: PhotoStory,
  video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
  const SpecificStory = components[props.storyType];
  return <SpecificStory story={props.story} />;
}
```

It is just a function that returns a template with the right component (depends on props)

In Vue we can do the same logic using:

```
<template>    
  <component :is="currentComponent"></component>
</template>
```

and *currentComponent* will be a computed property(usually) or just a property in a data

My question is: what option is cheaper for the performance and rendering?

Comment: I don't know Vue at all, but since that react component is just a function, it doesn't really matter how you get that function, it renders the same. And accessing a property of an object is very fast. So, at least in React, there would be _nearly_ zero performance cost.

Comment: Both options will have negligible performance impact. What matters more is what components are being rendered/destroyed, rather than the method of switching between them.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to load the component dynamically then you would go for computed property because the property value is dynamic and should be on state and i guess you are using vuex to retrive the data using ...mapGetters on computed property.

Using data property is mainly used for fixed values or declaration